# How to make citations appear within parentheses () instead of square brackets [ ]?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

I am using the `vancouver.bst` which conforms to the ICMJE (international committee of medical journal editors) How do I make the citations in the text appear in parentheses, e.g., `(3)`, rather than in brackets `[3]`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 5):

The style `vancouver` is compatible with the package `natbib`. So you can load the package `natbib` with the option `round` to achieve your requirements.

```
\documentclass[]{article} 
\usepackage[numbers,round]{natbib}
\begin{document}
\cite{book-full}
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I now need to get consecutive citations in the text to go from (1,2,3) to (1--3)....any ideas?

Comment: ...I just found it. I used \usepackage[numbers,round,sort&compress]{natbib} Thanks again.

Comment: @user2414716: Your  second question doesn't belong to your original question. The format of our site prefer asking a new/separate question.